# Call javascript function from other page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 pages one.html and two.html. Now I am getting an input on one.html and i have to  pass that and  call a JS function on two.html.

This is because using the input passed, i am modifying the elements of two.html using jquery.
So is it possible to pass the parameters and call a JS function on another page?

Comment: You only have 1 page active at once - you can't "run something on another page" because there is only 1 page.  What you can do is store the information as a cookie, or in localStorage, and then use that when you do go to the 2nd page.

Comment: page1.html is one.html you mean ?

Comment: You simply go to the next page attaching some parameters .../index.html?a=yes

Comment: You can pass parameters via the url or cookie, but the pages are not connected.

Comment: @AbdelrahmanTarekWahdan yes.

Comment: @Huangism i dont have to go to next page. simply call the function of another page

Comment: @Diffy If you are not going to the next page then I don't think you can do that

Comment: `This is because using the input passed, i am modifying the elements of two.html using jquery.` That makes no sense.  You cannot modify a page unless it is in your browser at the time. (Well okay, there are ways to do certain things but not what you're talking about).

Comment: Okay @Archer. i was just looking for a way to solve a problem in my project. I will look into the possibilities

Comment: @Diffy - this is an X/Y problem.  You're asking us how to do what you think the solution to your problem is.  You should really tell us the actual problem and let us help solve that.

Comment: @Archer. my actual problem is very broad. I am working on a e-commerce platform and stuck on how to add products to cart from another page, which is what i need. However i cant explain the whole situation here

Comment: @Diffy.  Move the function into a common js file that you include in the header of both pages, then they can both call it.  I understand now.  It can be done either by calling the cart page with the product info in the querystring (basket.aspx?cmd=add&product=123&qty=2 for example) or by an ajax call, which is how I presume you are doing it, since it's done from a javascript call.